# how to create a report for contacts without accounts

Tags: lightning-experience, reporting

we discovered that some customer can't sign up to Customer Community because they exists as Contact without account.

Business can't see such contact (and see only the contact related to the account coming from Datastore).

We need a report to list those contact without Accounts related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom report type like this:-

[image]

and then build report like this:-

[image]

It shows all the contacts in the system if you have access to them. Read more here:- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_manage_report_type.htm&type=5

### UPDATE

Make sure to add AccountId in custom report type layout and Just add the filter saying AccountId = null

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank uou for your answer 
I want juste contacts without account can you explain me how to filter them in the report

Comment: @Zak you can check the updated screenshots

Comment: thank you so much for your help